# Python kivy with open adding backslashes, throws invalid argument on replacing

Tags: python, file, kivy

I am trying to open a text file in my kivy app. The code is as follows:

```
class kivyx(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    message = StringProperty('Drop Test')
        
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.on_file_drop)
        print("MDlabel")
        return MDLabel(text=self.message, halign="center")

    def on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        self.message = str(file_path)
        path = str(file_path)[1:]
        getPath(path)

        return MDLabel(text=self.message, halign="center")

def getPath(path):
    print(path)
    with open(path.replace("\\\\", "/"), "r") as f:
        print(f.read())

kivyx().run()
```

this is my response:

```
MDlabel
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
'C:\\AMFTrace.log'
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:/dev/SpectrumX/kivyx.py", line 33, in <module>
     kivyx().run()
   File "C:\Users\tkulk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\tkulk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 572, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\tkulk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 349, in mainloop
     self.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\tkulk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 575, in mainloop
     self.dispatch('on_dropfile', dropfile[0])
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1172, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "d:/dev/SpectrumX/kivyx.py", line 24, in on_file_drop
     getPath(path)
   File "d:/dev/SpectrumX/kivyx.py", line 30, in getPath
     with open(path.replace("\\\\", "/"), "r") as f:
 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "'C:/AMFTrace.log'"
```

This works in the python interpreter, but its adding four backslashes when i use:

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
```

so I added the replace. What might be the issue?

It also works when I define the path directly,

```
with open("C:/AMFTrace.log", "r") as f:
```

But it should not matter as both are of type

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: You are somehow getting the path in a form with single quotes around it - note that the `print` output includes quotes, and the error message includes two sets of quotes.

Comment: Thanks. slicing the quotes using [1:][:-1] solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was somehow getting the path in a form with single quotes around it - note that the print output includes quotes, and the error message includes two sets of quotes.
Slicing the quotes using [1:][:-1] solved it.